# What are the conjugacy classes in $D_4$?

Tags: group-theory

Let G be group of all symmetries of square. Find number of conjugate classes in G.

I tried this question just as we do for $S_n$ that the number of conjugate classes in $S_n $ is partition number of n i.e. p (n) , where p (n) is partition function. 
Here we have in question given G=$ D_4$ so we should have number of conugacy classes = p (4)=5. But in book answer is6.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: The group is small enough, only 8 elements you could easily compute them by hand . Have you tried that ?

Comment: I didn't do it but lets try, different ways to write 4 are: 4, 3+1, 2+1+1,2+2, 1+1+1+1. Right?

Comment: No that's not the usual $D_4$ Look up the definition start here for example http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/d4/

Comment: You need to know the 8 elements in the group and you need to understand the binary operation as defined for $D_4$

Comment: Try to start by presenting your group by generators and relations. From there it should be easy.

Comment: Can you elaborate?. I thought number of partition of n gives number of conjugacy classes of $ S_n $ as well as $ D_n $. Isn't that correct?

Comment: In $S_n$ the conjugacy classes correspond to the different cycle structures. Those can be found by partitioning $n$. But in dihedral groups the number of conjugacy classes of $D_{2n}$ depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: @Foggy: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825592

Comment: @userX by "by hand" do mean to calculate $h^{-1}gh$ for all 64 pairs of $(g,h)$?

Answer (score 4):

One way to think about this problem is the following: think of conjugacy classes as group elements **up to change of basis**.

The identity transformation is in a single conjugacy class.

Any reflection about a diagonal is in a single conjugacy class.

Any reflection without fixed points (i.e. a reflection through the middle of opposite edges) is one class.

You can also rotations 90 degrees.

And 180 degrees rotations.

-

In total, these elements make up all the 8 elements of $D_4$, hence there are 5 conjugacy classes.

Comment: It would be more beneficial if there was a general approach for $ D_n $ for any n

Answer (score 2):

For any $x \in D_4$, the conjugacy class of $x$ denoted by $\text{Cl}(x)$ is:

$\text{Cl}(x) = \{gxg^{-1} : g ∈ D_4 \} $

You will get,

$\text{Cl}(R_0) = \{ R_0\}$

$\text{Cl}(R_{180}) = \{R_{180}\}$

$\text{Cl}(R_{90}) = \text{Cl}(R_{270})$

$\text{Cl}(H) = \text{Cl}(V)$

$\text{Cl}(D) = \text{Cl}(D')$

So we get 5 distinct conjugacy classes.